# Disable Hover on Menu with CSS

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation, css, js-css

I've been trying to solve this one for a week - i'm sure it's simple but i'm really struggling with it!

I am trying to change my navigation so that users have to click on it for it to appear. I believe the Magento default is that they just hover, at least that's what's happening on mine. Someone told me that they believe this is affected with CSS classes which I think might be right. It's worth noting that my mobile version (when viewed on a desktop) does enable clicks, but the desktop shows on hover.

Here is my CSS for nav-primary:

```
.nav-primary a {
color:#9a9a9a;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-primary a:hover {
color:#000;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 11px;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

#header-account li a,
.nav-primary a.level0 {
width: 200px;
text-align: left;
color: #636363;
text-transform: uppercase;
line-height: 20px;
padding-top: 0;
padding-right: 15px;
padding-bottom: 0;
margin-left: 300px;
}

#header-account li:last-child a,
.nav-primary li.level0:last-child a.level0 {
border-bottom: 0;
}

.no-touch #header-account a:hover,
.no-touch .nav-primary a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
}

.nav-primary {
display: block;
padding-top: 30px;
}

.nav-primary a {
text-decoration: none;
position: relative;
display: block;
color: #636363;
line-height: 30px;
font-family: "Raleway", "Helvetica Neue", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.nav-primary li {
position: relative;
}

.nav-primary li.level1 a {
margin-left: 350px;
}

.nav-primary .menu-active > ul.level0,
.nav-primary li.level0 li.sub-menu-active > ul {
 display: block;
 }

.nav-primary li.level0 > a {
text-transform: uppercase;
}

/* ============================================ *
* Small Viewports - Accordion Style Menu
* ============================================ */
.nav-primary a.level0,
.nav-primary a {
 line-height: 25px;
 }
 .nav-primary li.level0 ul {
 display: none;
 }
.nav-primary li.level0 li {
 padding: 0 0 0 25px;
 }
 .nav-primary li.level1 a {
 padding: 0 15px 0 25px;
 }
.nav-primary li.parent > a:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 display: block;
 border-top: 5px solid transparent;
 border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
 border-left: 5px solid #cccccc;
 border-right: none;
 top: 50%;
 left: 10px;
 right: auto;
 margin-top: -5px;
 }
 .nav-primary li.parent.sub-menu-active > a:after,
 .nav-primary li.parent.menu-active > a:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 display: block;
 border-right: 5px solid transparent;
 border-left: 5px solid transparent;
 border-top: 5px solid #cccccc;
 border-bottom: none;
 top: 50%;
 left: 10px;
 right: auto;
 margin-top: -5px;
 }
.nav-primary li.menu-active > a,
.nav-primary li.sub-menu-active > a {
 color: #000;
 }
/* ============================================ *
 * Large Viewports - Dropdown Menu
 * ============================================ */

 .nav-primary li.menu-active > ul {
 display: block;
 }
```

This is the one that makes them either appear on hover or just be there:

```
.nav-primary li.level0 ul { display: none; }
```

but i'm not sure what to change it to to go from hover to click?

UPDATE:

I have changed the code in my /app.js to the following and it seems to be working!

```
mouseClickAction: function(event, target) {
    if(this.useSmallScreenBehavior()) {
        return; // don't do mouse enter functionality on smaller screens
    }

    $j(target).addClass('menu-active'); //show current menu
},

/**
 * On large screens, hide menu.
 * On small screens, do nothing.
 *
 * @param event
 * @param target
 */
mouseClickAction: function(event, target) {
    if(this.useSmallScreenBehavior()) {
        return; // don't do mouse leave functionality on smaller screens
    }

    $j(target).removeClass('menu-active'); //hide all menus
},

/**
 * On large screens, don't interfere so that browser will follow link.
 * On small screens, toggle menu visibility.
 *
 * @param event
 * @param target
 */
mouseClickAction: function(event, target) {
    {
        event.preventDefault(); //don't follow link
        this.toggleMenuVisibility(target); //instead, toggle visibility
    }
},
```

I basically now have it doing the same as the small screen version; whereby users click to display the next category which is great! I do have a couple of categories that are meant to display a static block instead of divert to the page which now isn't working. Any idea how to still allow static blocks to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector you specified is adding display:none which is hiding your drop downs. That could remain the same, what you need to change is the part that shows them. It looks like that is done by this selector 
".nav-primary .menu-active > ul.level0" which makes the menu item display:block again. What you really need to change is the JavaScript that adds the "menu-active" class to the top level ul in the menu, in the rwd theme that would be skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/app.js.

Comment: Thank you! I have changed my code and updated my question above with the new code. I do have a couple of pages though that are meant to show a static block when users click on the category rather than redirecting to the page, which is now no longer working. Any idea how to still get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for onClick event, which is typically done with jQuery and not CSS.  There is a CSS workaround involving use of checkbox.  See the [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19170781/show-hide-divs-on-click-in-html-and-css-without-jquery).

The [asker in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731457/hide-show-content-list-with-only-css-no-javascript-used) may have what you are looking for.